# Replace specific content in file

Tags: python

I have a file with below content

```
Location=Test;
SpaceId=10;
TestStationName=<User Input value>;
TestStationPreferredHost=TestStationHost;
TestStationPool=<User Input value>
```

Here I need to change `<User Input value>` value which is dynamic in nature.

Example:

```
Location=Test;
SpaceId=10;
TestStationName=IND-TEST-50;
TestStationPreferredHost=TestStationHost;
TestStationPool=XYZ
```

Here the value is `IND-TEST-50` and `XYZ` at the end. This value has to be changed with user input.

Note: `TestStationName` will be different for different test machine.

I have done this like below. Is there any other efficient way to approach this?

I have used list for storing data and to update the data.

```
data1 = []
with open("INFO.txt") as f:
    data = f.readline()
    data1 = data.split(";")

print(data1)

data1[2] = "TestStationName" + "=" + "Value"

data1[4] = "TestStationPool" + "="+ "<Value>"

result = ""
for val in data1:
    result = result + val + ";"

with open("INFO.txt", "a") as f:
    f.write(result)
```

I am getting expected value with extra semi colon at the end.

Comment: Your are storing `result` with semi colon at the end. That is what the issue or is it something else? Let me know.

Comment: @TonyMontana thank you for the valuable comment. I don't need that semi colon at  the end. And is there any other way to make this code efficient?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with this:

```
for val in data1:
    result += val + ";"

result = result.rstrip(";")
```

Edit: More efficient solution

```
result = ";".join(data1)
```

Comment: Also, if your problem is solved then kindly mark it solved.